# INSERT multiple rows combined with an ID from the RETURNING clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, sql-insert, sql-returning

Here is my query:

```
WITH rows AS (INSERT INTO t_patch(f_name)VALUES('KB000')RETURNING f_patch_id)
INSERT INTO t_patch_available (f_patch_id, f_product_id)
SELECT f_patch_id,7 FROM rows;
```

It works. But what is the syntax if I want to insert several `t_patch_available` with the same `f_patch_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use union on the select to add more rows.

```
WITH rows AS (INSERT INTO t_patch(f_name)VALUES('KB001')RETURNING f_patch_id)
INSERT INTO t_patch_available (f_patch_id, f_product_id) 
SELECT f_patch_id,7 FROM rows 
UNION ALL SELECT f_patch_id, 8 FROM rows
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use one `SELECT` per row, that's needlessly verbose and expensive for more than a few rows. `CROSS JOIN` to a set of IDs (assuming product_id is `integer`).

```
WITH rows AS (INSERT INTO t_patch(f_name) VALUES ('KB000') RETURNING f_patch_id)
INSERT INTO t_patch_available (f_patch_id, f_product_id)
SELECT f_patch_id, product_id
FROM   rows
     , unnest ('{6,8,9,11,345}'::int[]) product_id;  -- set of product_id's
```

Or you can use a `VALUES` expression:

```
...
FROM   rows
    , (VALUES (6) ,(8), (9), (11), (345)) AS p(product_id);  -- set of product_id
```